# How to modify the behavior of a node in ns2 simulator?

Tags: c++, network-programming, tcl, simulator, ns2

I want to modify the behavior of a node in ns2 simulator. In particular, I have to modify a routing of a node inside a simulation of the dsr protocol. 
I know that dsragent.cc is the class that manages the routing of this protocol. But if I have a tcl script with 10 nodes, called $node1,$node2...node$10, how to modify the behavior of $node5 in the dsr protocol? How to find the single behavior of that node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had worked with other routing protocol but i will mention some points ..may it be useful.

in order to access specific node object in c++  you need to know its address in tcl. then you may need to make modification in forward or recv function..
you can extract all  information you need form common,IP,DSR headers

```
DSRAgent::recv(Packet* packet, Handler*)
  /* handle packets with a MAC destination address of this host, or
     the MAC broadcast addr */
{
       hdr_sr *srh =  hdr_sr::access(packet);
      hdr_ip *iph =  hdr_ip::access(packet);
      hdr_cmn *cmh =  hdr_cmn::access(packet);
      p.dest = ID((Address::instance().get_nodeaddr(iph->daddr())),::IP);
      p.src = ID((Address::instance().get_nodeaddr(iph->saddr())),::IP);
```

the following means.. if current node is the generator of the packet

```
 if (p.src == net_id) {code}
```

to select specific node object

```
 if (net_id==ID("put the node address here", ::IP))     \\ notice net_id is a struct 
     {
       your code here
     }
```

you can assign node address from tcl
and this address will be passed to c++ by command function

```
DSRAgent::command(int argc, const char*const* argv)
.
.
 if (strcasecmp(argv[1], "addr") == 0) 
    {
      int temp;
      temp = Address::instance().str2addr(argv[2]);
     net_id = ID(temp, ::IP);
     flow_table.setNetAddr(net_id.addr);
.
}
```

regards

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you help me for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359275/arrange-nodes-in-ns2 Thanks in advance.