# Arrange nodes in ns2

Tags: networking, network-programming, tcl, wireless, ns2

I need to arrange 100 nodes in a hexagonal shape in my tcl script. My simulation is wireless (dsr protocol). How can I do this? Which is the best size of the grid? I thought 3000x3000.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to build the network graphically .. you can use nsg tool to build the network and generate the tcl code very easily

http://www.nsnam.com/2013/04/ns2-scenario-generator.html

first you must determine the transition range of nodes, put required number of node-> get network size , or you can compute it mathematically using transmition range and hexagon aria

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon

If you plan to use nsg to draw a regular hexagon use this simple trick:

- if the transmition range is equal to 300 m then make it 250 m
- put first node in the center of the network.
- put two nodes in the border of first node coverage aria.
- put other nodes in the  4 Intersection of coverage area o previous 3 nodes.
- repeat previous steps for other hexagons.
- return the transmition range to its correct value (300 m).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the software but I didn't know how to configure the hexagon area.

Comment: Oh, great! My routing protocol is DSR. What is the best configuration for transmission/interference range? When I open NSG the default value for wireless scenario is 250 for transmission and 550 for interference. It is good?

Comment: it depends on the technology used in mac and phy  layers  (wifi 802.11,802.15.4,....." )

Comment: It is wifi 802.11

Comment: 250 m and 550 m  is the default value if you don't change parameters in tcl file in ns2... transmition range depends on the technology used in mac and phy  layers  (wifi 802.11,zigbee/lr-wpan 802.15.4,....." ), and changing  the interference range affects the packet collisions...in wifi you can use  the default value unless your application requires a specific  transmition range range

Comment: if your will use the default transmition range (250 m) then use (200) m in drawing the network to insure the connectivity

Comment: As you have been so helpful, I hope you don't mind me taking advantage of it. Could you please read my other question about ns2 and dsr protocol? Thank you in advance :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370370/edit-dsr-routing-protocol-in-ns2

Comment: of course, but first i must study some points about route request and route reply mechanism in DSR , i will do that when i have a time.
thanks for your kindness